# Difference in Forms Authentication between Razor Preview and Razor Beta?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm attempting to upgrade an MVC project to Beta using Razor (from the Preview release) and am now experiencing strangeness with Razor not going to my login view that it use to go to (when someone asks for an action that required authorization).

My web config has

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
```

But whenever an action with the Authorize attribute is hit, the browser redirects to "Account/Login" - notice Log**in** NOT Log**On**.  Anyone know how to fix this in MVC 3 Beta?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a known bug in Beta: [Release Notes: Chapter Known Issues](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#0.1__Toc274034230)

> There’s a known issue that causes Forms Authentication to always redirect unauthenticated users to /Account/Login, ignoring the forms authentication setting used in Web.config. The workaround is to add the following app setting.

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following the `<configuration>` section of your application's `Web.config` file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: I already had that set to false (was in the notes on converting to a mvc 3 beta app), doesn't effect it any.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to disable the `authentication mode="Forms"`.

I removed the authentication section and it started to work.

```
<!--
 <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
-->
```